# SEO : Move content with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, seo

I placed a text early in the html code for SEO reasons, but visually, this text should be at the bottom of the page. I can't do this with just CSS.
My question: is it a problem for SEO if I move the text in the DOM with javascript? Not hidden or removed, juste moved.

Thanks !

Comment: A SE shouldn't index text the user doesn't see when entering the page. BTW: google does execute your javascript and notices the text is at the bottom

Comment: @Bergi, as far as I know, Google does not execute javascript. They do however, manually check webpages that are suspect of using techniques to hide and/or modify data to mislead a user.

Comment: @PatrikAlienus: http://ipullrank.com/googlebot-is-chrome/ and http://www.seomoz.org/blog/just-how-smart-are-search-robots

Comment: OP, mark the answer you wanted with a checkmark, please. And register an account while you're at it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you placed your text in the beginning for SEO reasons, but moved it down because it isn't aimed at the user, Google will interpret that as misleading to the end-user. If they'll notice a single paragraph? Doubtful. But if you were to make this common practice, I believe this would go in the category of Blackhat SEO, even though it's mild in comparison to other things you **can** do.

You have to remember that visitors that end up on your site through Google, is a customer of Google. And if the user thinks he/she was mislead, it falls on Google not doing a good enough job. Keep that in mind when designing.

A tip, if you're looking for one, is to simply never do things like this. If you design your site and script your text well enough that the visitor finds it useful, Google will see that and ranking will follow. This has been my experience anyways - shortcuts have never worked out (for me) in the long run.

Comment: nice answer @Patrik Alienus. Will you please provide some good links or tips for SEO?

Comment: @KuKu I would suggest starting with Google. Their Webmasters Blog is a good blog to follow. Go to http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35291 for instance and click their Optimization Starter Guide. But truth be told, it's a painful trial-n-error process when you're just starting out. You should also try a search for "how does SEO work" on either Google or YouTube. There's also a few good books on the subject, I recently read "The New Google SEO" which I can recommend.

Answer (score 1):

Any "I want machine to see content more prominently, but obscure it from user" action is simply called [cloaking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloaking) and will reflect negatively on your index once caught.

How much will it take? Depends on many factors, including complains from users lured to your site if it indeed have nothing but "SEO reasons" to it.

Answer (score 1):

The most important content first is good SEO practice.

You cannot say that moving content around is bad SEO practice per se. Take a look at the HTML of wikipedia for example. The content of a detail page (the article) within the HTML is before the HTML of the navigation, for example. 
The bot will see it more prominently, it's the most important thing on the page and that's it.

Another example: Why should it be bad practive to place content first in the HTML and "move up" a slider with some images, completely coded in JS? Things like that.

In one video on YT Matt Cutts discusses a similar question with Javascript and dialog elements that toggle the display of texts (show/hide) which is quite common. As long as typical phrases are used (on, off, more, see more, things like that) and you use common tools you don't look suspicious.

As usual, the devil will be in the details.

Comment: No one has said that moving content is bad, unless you're doing it for the purpose of deceiving search engines. For example, would it be OK to switch positions of two different h2 tags with their respective paragraphs? One may be SEO-friendly, but one may be better for the user. So, is that OK? If I've interpreted everything Google has ever said on the matter, it's not. However moving content in the visual presentation to make something better (fine line here...) for the user, is considered ay-ok.

Comment: @PatrikAlienus I tend to read the question more neutral and don't assume he wants to trick the bot. Then there is a lot of room for unproblematic HTML, CSS and JS work. These questions come up because you can have the best intentions and get a penalty. For example: Would (a) you and/or (b) the searchengine have to feel tricked because I have a page with perfectly hierarchical semantical HTML content - but my designer displays all the content with a 11px font? In my opinion that's perfectly ok. And in the SE's, too.

Comment: I interpreted "for SEO reasons" differently then, I guess :-)